# Are these two Banach spaces isometrically isomorphic?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $c$ denote the space of convergent sequences in $\mathbb C$, $c_0\subset c$ be the space of all sequences that converge to $0$. Given the uniform metric, both of them can be made into Banach spaces. It can be shown that the dual spaces of them are isometrically isomorphic, i.e. $c^*\cong c_0^*$. Are $c$ and $c_0$ isometrically isomorphic? If not, how can one show the absence of such a isometric isomorphism? Thanks!

Comment: That's a nice question. I must admit that I never asked this myself. After thinking for a bit and getting nowhere, I've looked in some of the obvious places, but I couldn't find a reference addressing it. Pełczyński and Bessaga mention that $c_0$ is *not* isometrically isomorphic to any space $C(K)$ with $K$ compact [see here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/or/or2/or214.pdf) (last paragraph before 10.9 on page 261) but they give no hint at the proof. It might be proved in H. Elton Lacey's [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=U1mqAAAAIAAJ), but I don't have a copy handy.

Comment: Not an isometry, but $c$ and $c_0$ are isomorphic in an obvious way: Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a convergent sequence of complex numbers. We denote its limit by $a_\ast = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$. We obtain an operator $F: c \to c_0$ with $F(a_n) = (a_\ast, a_1 - a_\ast, a_2 - a_\ast, \dots)$. A routine calculation shows $F$ to be linear and continuous with $\Vert F \Vert = 2$. On the other hand we have $G: c_0 \to c$ with $G(a_n) = (a_1 + a_2, a_1 + a_3, a_1 + a_4, \dots)$. Again a routine calculation shows that $FG = id$, $GF = id$ and $\Vert G \Vert = 2$.

Comment: Alexander's comment above says that the Banach-Mazur distance $d_{BM}(c,c_0)$ of $c$ and $c_0$ is no larger than $4$, where $d_{BM}(X,Y) = \inf \Vert T\Vert\cdot \Vert T^{-1}\Vert$, where the infimum is taken over the set of all isomorphisms of $X$ onto $Y$ (if this set is empty - that is, $X$ is not isomorphic to $Y$ - we write $d_{BM}(X,Y) =\infty$). In general, getting an upper bounds on $d_{BM}(X,Y)$ for isomorphic $X$ and $Y$ is fairly easy. Getting a nontrivial lower bound when $X$ and $Y$ are not known to be isometrically isomorphic seems to be quite difficult in general. It just so...

Comment: happens that the precise value of $d_{BM}(c,c_0)$ is known and equal to $3$; this is due to Michael Cambern; see [On mappings of sequence spaces](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm30/sm3017.pdf), Studia Math. **30** (1968), 73--77. On a further tangential point Cambern showed in another paper that if $K$ and $L$ are compact Hausdorff spaces with $d_{BM}(C(K),C(L))<2$, then $K$ and $L$ are homeomorphic - hence $d_{BM}(C(K),C(L))=1$. For this, see [On isomorphisms of small bound](http://dx.doi.org/doi:10.1090/S0002-9939-1967-0217580-2), Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. **18** (1967), 1062--1066.

Comment: A recent question on MathOverflow about this: [$c_0$ is not isometrically isomorphic to $c$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/300108#comment746858_300108).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The closed unit ball of $c_0$ has no extreme points. The closed unit ball of $c$ has many extreme points, such as $(1,1,\ldots)$. Since the property of being an extreme point is preserved by isometries, $c$ and $c_0$ are not isometrically isomorphic.