# A Banach space with multiple preduals

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Is it possible to have two (separable) Banach spaces, $X$ and $Y$, that are not isometrically isomorphic, and yet their dual spaces $X^*$ and $Y^*$ are isometrically isomorphic?

Comment: $\ell_1$, has   $c_0$ and $c$ (the space of bounded sequences that have a limit at infinity with the sup norm) as pre-duals. $c$ and $c_0$ are not isometrically isomorphic. There are many other pre-duals of $\ell_1$.

Comment: @DavidMitra: That is an answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. For example, $\ell_1$, has $c_0$ and $c$ (the space of sequences that have a limit at infinity with the sup norm) as pre-duals. $c$ and $c_0$ are not isometrically isomorphic (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80727/are-these-two-banach-spaces-isometrically-isomorphic/80811#80811)). There are many other pre-duals of $\ell_1$.

See [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/michigan-mathematical-journal/volume-24/issue-3/On-Banach-spaces-with-unique-isometric-preduals/10.1307/mmj/1029001949.full) for some results on when a Banach space has a unique isometric predual.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize there was such an easy example

Comment: After thinking more I am especially embarrassed, being an operator algebraist. Namely given $C^*$-algebras A and B, consider the von Neumann algebra $A^{**}$ and $B^{**}$. Any vN algebra has a unique predual. So if $A^{**}=B^{**}$ then $A^*=B^*$. But we can get this with many different $A$ and $B$.