# Existence of points in closed and bounded convex sets that cannot be expressed as convex combination of other elements of the set.

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

I have an intuition about convex, closed, bounded sets but I can't really find a way to prove whether it's right or wrong.

Let $\Sigma$ be a convex set, that means, that given any $A,B \in \Sigma$, and $\lambda \in [0,1]$, $C = \lambda A + (1 - \lambda) B \in \Sigma$. This set $\Sigma$ is closed and bounded under some metric $\| \|$.
I'd like to prove that, the set $G = \{ A \in \Sigma: \nexists B,C \in \Sigma \text{ and } \lambda \in (0,1) \text{ s.t. } A = \lambda B + (1-\lambda) C \} \neq \emptyset $.

In plain words, that there exists elements that cannot be expressed as a convex combination of other elements in $\Sigma$.

My intuition comes from polygons where it's easy to see that their vertices can't be expressed as convex combinations of other points within the polygon.

Comment: I think you're talking about extreme points. IIRC:  In any locally convex Hausdorff topological vector space, any  compact convex set has extreme points. The locally convex assumption is needed, as an [example](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm60/sm60119.pdf) of James Roberts shows (see [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDUQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mat.unimi.it%2Fusers%2Flibor%2FAnConvessa%2Fext.pdf&ei=XUGwUrj7JMqCyQG2ioDIBQ&usg=AFQjCNE_h5wR7qrAR09rXf9fNNyMEZQdNg&bvm=bv.58187178,d.aWc&cad=rja) paper for some results).

Comment: per my last comment, compactness is also crucial. For example, the closed unit ball of the space $c_0$ has no extreme points. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585412/verify-that-the-unit-closed-ball-in-c-0-has-not-extremal-points?lq=1). (So your conjecture is false in the infinite dimensional case. I'm not sure about finite dimensional spaces.)

Comment: @DonAntonio, it is not enough to be in the boundary. If we imagine a square in $R^2$. Let us concentrate on a side excluding its extremes. Every point is in the boundary (since the side of the square is part of the boundary) but it can be expressed as a convex combination of the extremes of this side.

Comment: @DavidMitra, I'm having a look at your doc. It does seem that this is what I'm after. I do agree in your claim about the compactness, because I came from the $R^2$ intuition, I've (wrongly) assumed that closed+bounded = compact.

Comment: @Sam, correct. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, the theorem mentioned in my first comment is known as the Krein-Milman Theorem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me go through this, and I'll post a summary later. It's always a good exercise to see if I fully understand the proof.